# Set postition of New Form related to Control

Tags: vb.net

I'm stuck with basic's.

Here I need to place New Form "myForm2" in place of DataGridView's "myDgv" location.
Here is my approach:

```
Dim fl As New myForm2

fl.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
Dim p As Point = Me.PointToScreen(myDgv.Location)
fl.Location = p
fl.Show(Me)
```

Showed code places myForm2 at top-left position of the screen.
How to get it to place myForm2 at the top-left position of myDgv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the screen-coordinates of the grid:

```
Dim pt As Point = myDgv.PointToScreen(Point.Empty)
```

Then set the location of the form:

```
fl.Location = pt
```

Comment: It still don't pop at place of myDgv location. Anything missing here?

Comment: This won't work when the taskbar is on the left or the top.  It is just not meant to do this.

Comment: @HansPassant You're absolutely right. Setting the location property should be enough.

Comment: I get it! Here was a problem that new form changes Font during load and then replaces this form to different location. Thank's Bjorn, it works.

Comment: Hi Bjorn, previous version work better because if I move main form with this solution myForm2 appear on previous location.